# How can i cancel an order of a customer and reorder in Magento2 using REST API

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.4

I would like to add the options to the customer to cancel their orders and Re-order option for the desired products at customer dashboard.

By using REST API, How can i cancel and reorder items?

Please check the following attachment for the reference.

[image]

Comment: It should be a POST . you are using GET . this is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

in headers pass token and pass order as shown in image

Comment: My products API returns products, if i try with customer i am getting error, my url : http://192.168.1.65/anusthana/api/rest/customers error : https://snag.gy/0jbhTr.jpg  can u help me

Answer (score 3):

Magento already have an in build api point by which you can cancel an order

> http://www.example.com/rest/V1/orders/78/cancel

where  78 is an order id

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://example.com/rest/V1/orders/1/cancel",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer qctyw0k8uc7svw6m7hwwl58ws3twymts",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: what should i pass in headers for rest api and should i pass any content in body

Comment: Please see the  example

Comment: i have done in the same way as shown in example but iam getting response Request does not match any route.

Comment: @AmitBera, I am facing same error while i was tried with customer token.